# Some bold characters in mathbf being overriden by the main math font with unicode-math

Tags: fonts, bold, unicode-math

I want to automatically use `FiraMath-Bold` font inside the `mathbf` enviroments but some characters and symbols like the square root, equal sign and parentheses doesn't seem to  being render in bold but rather to be overriden by the main math font. I'm currently using `unicode-math` but i'm open to use `mathspec` if it solves the problem.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[
    Extension      = .otf,
    UprightFont    = FiraMath-Light,
    BoldFont       = FiraMath-Bold
]{FiraMath}
\setmathfont[Extension = .otf]{FiraMath-Light}
\setmathfontface\mathbf[Extension = .otf]{FiraMath-Bold}
\setmathfont[version = bold, Extension = .otf]{FiraMath-Bold}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Example:}
    
    Square root in light weight inside mathbf a enviroment:
    \begin{equation}
        \mathbf{\Delta = \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}
    \end{equation}
    
    Expected behaviour:
    \begin{equation}
        \mathversion{bold} \Delta = \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Since the beginning of its existence, about 30 years ago, the command `\mathbf` has never acted on symbols, but just on letters.

Comment: you want `\boldmath` (for the whole expression) or `\bm` (for subterms) but at https://github.com/firamath/firamath/releases or in texlive I do not see either light or bold versions of fira math? are these fonts available? I only Have FiraMath-Regular.otf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the multiples weights are in the 0.4v beta release or you can get it also in the latest snapshot

Comment: I still don't see it at that repository, Please add a link in your question are you using a fork or do you mean there is a 0,4 branch there?

Comment: https://github.com/firamath/firamath/releases/tag/v0.4-beta-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `\boldsymbol` command (from `amsbsy`, which `unicode-math` loads indirectly).  This sets the contents in `\mathversion{bold}`.  The `\setmathfont[range=bfup]` command will change the `\symbfup` command, but not `\mathbf` or `\boldmath`.

By the way, you do not want to set `\mathbf` as a math font face.  The way to do this would be

```
\setmathrm{FiraSans}[
  UprightFont=*-Light,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  ItalicFont=*-LightItalic,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldItalic,
  Extension=.otf]
```

This will change `\mathrm`, `\mathbf`, `\mathit` and `\mathbfit`.  By default, these are set to the main font family, so you will only need to change them if you want a different one.

These alphabets are intended for words in math mode, whereas `\symup`, `\symbfup`, and so on are meant for stand-alone math symbols.  You will see a huge difference between `\mathrm{iff}` (interpreted as a word that should have ligatures) and `\symup{iff}` (interpreted as the product of the constants *i*, *f* and *f*).

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Format a MWE for TeX.SX
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{FiraSans}
\setmathfont[Extension = .otf]{FiraMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[version = bold, FakeBold=1.5, Extension = .otf]{FiraMath-Regular}
\setboldmathrm{FiraSans}[
  UprightFont=*-Bold,
  BoldFont=*-ExtraBold,
  ItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  BoldItalicFont=*-ExtraBoldItalic,
  Extension=.otf]

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Example:}
    
     This \textbf{should} work for you:
    \begin{equation}
        \boldsymbol{\Delta = \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}
    \end{equation}
    
    Expected behaviour:
    \begin{equation}
        \mathversion{bold} \Delta = \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}
    \end{equation}

  Math alphabets in regular math:
  \mathversion{normal}
  \[ \mathrm{mathrm} \; \mathit{mathit} \; \mathbf{mathbf} \; \mathbfit{mathbfit}
  \]

  Math alphabets in bold math:
  \begingroup\mathversion{bold}
  \[ \mathrm{mathrm} \; \mathit{mathit} \; \mathbf{mathbf} \; \mathbfit{mathbfit}
  \]
  \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: Fira sample]

I don’t have any weight of Fira Math other than Regular, so I substituted `FakeBold` here.

Answer (score 2):

`\mathbf` is not the correct way to go, because it only acts on letters. And if you want it to act on `\Delta` you need `\symbf`.

You can define an environment that makes *everything* `\boldmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{FiraSans}[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *-Light,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
]
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular}[
  Extension = .otf
]
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Bold}[
  version = bold,
  Extension = .otf,
]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{makebold}{m}
 {\boldmath\csname #1\endcsname}
 {\csname end#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Example:}
    
Square root in light weight inside mathbf a enviroment:
\begin{equation}
  \symbf{\Delta = \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}
\end{equation}
    
Expected behaviour:
\begin{makebold}{equation}
  \Delta = \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}
\end{makebold}

\begin{makebold}{align}
  \Delta &= \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \\
  \Delta &= \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}
\end{makebold}

\end{document}
```

The square root doesn't appear, but this seems to be a problem with the math font, which is in beta version.

[image]